# how to create a webpage UI on AWS that can show data from MYSQL in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, user-interface, web-applications, html

I have a database on AWS RDS MYSQL Server. I want to create a webpage on my website that can give a login ID and Password and let users access the database in a Clean UX manner.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic scripts you'll need to connect to your database and provide login functionality on a web page.

Config.php - global configurations

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3036');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'rootpassword');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Login.php - login function

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: welcome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
<html>
```

welcome.php - welcome page after successful login

```
<?php
   include('session.php');
?>
<html">

   <head>
      <title>Welcome </title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 
      <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
   </body>

</html>
```

logout.php - redirects to login after successful logout

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if(session_destroy()) {
      header("Location: login.php");
   }
?>
```

session.php - verifies session

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from admin where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.php");
   }
?>
```